# Facebook is only displaying preview thumbnails that are 100px from my posts?

Tags: post-thumbnails, facebook

I'm using [Facebook and Digg Thumbnail generator](http://www.fedmich.com/tools/facebook-and-digg-thumbnail-generator) and [FaceBook Share (New)],
[2](http://www.appointy.com/web/facebookshare)

As you can see if the image is 100px the thumbail is displayed when I press the share button:

[image]

But with an image with 300px of width:

[image]

The thumb preview doesn't appear:

[image]

**front-page.php:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Front Page
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Prominent
 * @since Prominent 1.0
 */
get_header(); ?>
<div id="tagline">
    <div class="container">
    </div><!-- .container -->
</div><!-- #tagline -->
<div id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="mainbar">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="content-block-2">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php /* Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable */ ?>
            <?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
                <div id="prev"><?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; Older posts', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
                <div id="next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts &rarr;', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- #mainbar -->
    </div><!-- .container -->
</div><!-- #content-bottom -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Any suggestion to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out why. Facebook only allows images with 3:1 ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You can add [Open Graph tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) to your templates hint to Facebook for what images and text to use.